# 3rd party content images don't have alt attributes and meeting WCAG 2.0 Level A - javascript solution?

Tags: javascript, accessibility, alt, wcag2.0

We have some 3rd party content coming into one of our websites that need to adhere to WCAG 2.0 Level A requirements. 
The html coming in through the RSS feed doesn't provide proper alt attributes to the img tags. We were hoping to add the alt attributes using javascript. Although that doesn't make the code great if javascript is turned off, it is a lot better.

This thread
[WCAG 2.0 level A and AJAX generated content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16861246/wcag-2-0-level-a-and-ajax-generated-content)
 seems to imply that using other js methods with WCAG 2.0 Level A aren't a problem. I assume it would then be alright in this example.

Comment: How are you going to programatically determine suitable alternative text?

Answer (score 3):

The use of javascript does not effect WCAG compliance unless you are using javascript in a way that breaks a WCAG guideline. As a screen reader user while this will technically meet the guidelines how are you going to make sure the alt tags have actual meaning? I would rather have no alt tag rather then a misleading one.

Comment: proof from the source! @jared seriously great input! i know you're just throwing your two cents in, and I still applaud you. bravo!

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption is right, as @Jared said JavaScript by itself isn't breaking WCAG compliance, unless used in a way that breaks accessibility.

I am also a screenreader user and hate when it reads the long awkward file name instead of a proper or empty alt text.

If you can't find a way to identify a suitable `alt` text you should insert an empty alt attribute (`alt=""`), so that screenreades won't focus/read the image. Personally I've noticed that some screenreaders focus and read the empty `alt` anyway, so I use the ARIA attribute `aria-hidden="true" so that the browser wont send the image through the Accessibility API.

Here is a jQuery example of detecting all images without an `alt` attribute and inserting an empty one.

```
$('img:not([alt])').each(function() {
  $(this).attr('alt', '');
  $(this).attr('aria-hidden', 'true');
});
```